# runlevel is return unknown in teminal

Tags: init, runlevel

I put in my terminal command:

```
$ runlevel
```

and it return me instead some:

```
init num
```

just:

```
unknown
```

I use Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: I do not think systemd uses run levels

Comment: https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-systemd-runlevels-and-service-management-commands

Comment: FTR I'm using `systemd` under Ubuntu 16.04.3 and kernel 4.14.27. Calling `runlevel` returns `N 5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runlevel` is obsolete but you cat still print the current run level by running:

```
$ who -r
run-level 5  2018-03-31 13:10
```